# pasar imagenes guardas en arraylist a html java Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Quisiera pasar un conjunto de imagenes desde una url a traves de un `arraylist` en java spring boot,
el anunciado es el siguiente:

Debe crear un controlador para la raíz de la url. Este controlador debe manipular el archivo de
texto plano que proporciona la información de las noticias que se deben mostrar, se recuerda
que la separación entre noticias es el salto de línea y entre el contenido de la noticias son dos
símbolos de arroba @@. Para esta tarea utilice los métodos de `FileReader` y `BufferedReader` de
la librería `java.io` y almacene las noticias en un `ArrayList<String>` .
y el tema es el siguiente:

```
@Controller
public class NoticiasController {
     private final static Logger logger =
             LoggerFactory.getLogger(NoticiasController.class);
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String noticias(Model model)
    {
        
        
        String nombre = "src/main/resources/static/noticias.txt";
         ArrayList<String> p = new ArrayList<>();
         try {
             FileReader fr = new FileReader(nombre);
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
             
             
             
             String data = br.readLine();
             
             String[ ]split= data.split("@@");
             
                 
                 for(int i = 0; i < split.length; i++){
                        p.add(split[i]);
            

             
             data = br.readLine();
             
                    }

             br.close();
             fr.close();

             } catch (Exception e) {
                 logger.error("Error leyendo el fichero "+ nombre + ": " + e);
             }
            
         
         model.addAttribute("noticia1",p.get(0));
         
         model.addAttribute("noticia2",p.get(1));
         
         model.addAttribute("noticia3",p.get(2));

        return "noticias";
        
        
    }
```

y el html vendria siendo el siguiente

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th = "http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title> Noticias </title>
</head>
<body>

        
<ul>
  <li th:each="variable : ${p}" th:text="${noticia1}"></li>
</ul>
        <p th:text="'Noticia: ' + ${noticia1}" />
        <p th:text="'Noticia: ' + ${noticia2} " />
    
    
    
        <img src="${noticia3}" />

</body>
</html>
```

Necesito que me queden 2 parrafos y abajo la imagen de la noticia, no encuentro como hacerlo, estaria muy agradecido si alguien me pudiese hechar una mano, no encontre mas info por ningun lado.

Answer (score 2):

Ya lo resolvi, se hacia anteponiendo el th  de la siguiente manera:

```
    <img th:src=${noticia3}  />
```

Estaba omitiendo la expresion del Thymeleaf

Comment: Qué bien que encontraste la respuesta! Gracias por compartirla. Recuerda marcarla luego como aceptada para que otros sepan que esta es la solución